# jQuery regex can't match when string starts with "<" character

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying so see if the start of a string has the "<" character, but it will not work. It works fine in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/), but not when I try it in personal files.

Type in a `backslash` and it works fine, type in a `<` and it will not work.

```js
$(function() {

  $(document).on('keyup', '.input', function() {
    var str = $(this).html();

    // not working
    if (str.match(/^</)) {
      console.log('starts with "<" character');
    }

    // but this works??
    if (str.match(/^\\/)) {
      console.log('starts with backslash');
    }


  });

});
```

```css
.input {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input" contenteditable></div>
```

Comment: Your code should work (even without the backslash). Does the HTML element have a linebreak or space before the tag begins? That would make `(str.match(/^</))` fail.

Comment: `'<foo'.match(/^</)` works so my guess is there is something else. debug the string `console.log(escape(str))`

Comment: Does it work if you test the `innerHTML` property instead?

Comment: the `<` character was being replaced with `&lt;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript could be encoding the `<` symbol to `&lt;`. Try doing `console.log(str);` to take a look if this is happening (it did when I tried it in my browser).

If that's the case, replace the `<` symbol with `&lt;` in your pattern like so:

```
    if (str.match(/^&lt;/)) {
        console.log('starts with "<" character');
    }
```

Comment: This worked, could have sworn I tried that. Thanks!

Comment: @Souleste Simple thing to overlook. Glad that worked for you.